# Angular ngx-datatable link accountid to details page

Tags: javascript, angular

datatable for data table, this table have some static data with account number and other details this table row have a column with actions like view row and if i click on the button this show me a alert with details like below

```
 userdetails.component.ts

 rows: any = [
 {
  id: 0
  name: "Chao Lee",
  account: "112123100251",
  office: "Edinburgh",
  amount: "1000"
 },
 {
  id: 1
  name: "jan Lee",
  account: "112123100251",
  office: "Edinburgh",
  amount: "1000"
 }
]
```

this working fine but I wanted to show this data to a details page like if user click on the id from the table then this will go to details page with the id and show up details. I have done this like this

at component.html

```
 <ngx-datatable-column name="id" prop="id">
            <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-value="value">
              <a class="btn" (click)="ViewDetails(row.id)">
                {{row.id}} <!-- or {{value}} -->
              </a>
            </ng-template>
 </ngx-datatable-column>
```

and

component.ts

```
  ViewDetails(valObj){
  this.router.navigate(['/user/details/',valObj.id,{queryParams: {id: 
 valObj.id}}]);
}
```

but this not going to the details, showing me an error

```
ERROR Error: The requested path contains 
undefined segment at index 1
at validateCommands (router.js:4403)
at Router.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Router.navigate 
(router.js:4281)
```

Please help me to fix it

Comment: Paste the complete error, it looks like something is missing after ":"

Comment: I have updated the error and code also

Comment: What are you trying to do with that first valObj.id? does ```this.router.navigate(['/user/details/', {queryParams: {id: 
 valObj.id}}]); doesn't work?```

Comment: yes this not going to user details page, doesn't work

Comment: I have updated the code like this.router.navigate(['/user/details/',{id: valObj.id}]); this going to /user/details page but showing url like this /uer/details;id=undefined

Comment: I wanted to get user details based on id and show up at /user/details/1 page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing row.id

```
<a class="btn" (click)="ViewDetails(row.id)">
```

And then trying to access the id property of a number in ViewDetails

```
ViewDetails(valObj){ ----> this is an id (a number, not an object so you can't access valObj.id)
  this.router.navigate(['/user/details/',valObj.id,{queryParams: {id: 
 valObj.id}}]);
}
```

just change that "valObj" to "id" and instead of "valObj.id" just use "id"

rewrite your ViewDetails to

```
ViewDetails(id){
  this.router.navigate([`/user/details/${id}`);  // --> route param
}
```

**EDIT**

There are several ways to do this:

**Route params approach:**

In your routing.module.ts, write you user detail component route like this (if user is a parent route, it's ok as well, just write the :id param as a param of details):

```
{ path: 'user/details/:id', component: YourDetailsComponent }
```

Navigate with

```
ViewDetails(id){
  this.router.navigate([`/user/details`, id]); 
}
```

In your YourDetailsComponent component, inject ActivatedRoute:

```
private route: ActivatedRoute
```

and with

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

you would be able to access the id

**query params approach**:

```
ViewDetails(id){
  this.router.navigate([`/user/details`, {queryParams: { id: id }}]); 
}
```

you wouldn't need to use :id in the route, and you could access the query param with:

```
this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id')
```

Comment: yes this working fine but I am getting the url like this for details page /user/details;id=0 i am useing this code  this.router.navigate(['/user/details/',{id: id}]);

Comment: I updated my answer, use ```this.router.navigate([`/user/details/${id}`); ``` you don't need query params unless you actually need that id as a query param, remember query params are represented in the url at the end with ?key=value&key2=value2 ....

Comment: if i use this then showing me error like core.js:3866 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'angular2-multiselect'.
1. If 'angular2-multiselect' is an Angular component and it has 'data' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'angular2-multiselect' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA'

Comment: i don't see any data property in your question, is it possible that it is being used in the component you are navigating to?

Comment: I have missed it please suggest me what can i do, I wanted to show user details at details page like this have id: 0,
Acountnumber: "12125"
amount: "454",
date: "07/28/2020"

Comment: and where is your user detail data coming from?

Comment: this will come from users: any = [
    { id:0
      name: "Chao Lee",
      account: "112123100251",
      office: "Edinburgh",
      amount: "1000"
    }]  at userdetails.component.ts  so my plan is just get user id from querystring ?id=1 then will show up details at user details page from the rows jsons

Comment: this really works well, thank you so much for your hardwork

Comment: can you let me know please how can i get userdetails based on the id I got?

Comment: I'm glad to be helpful! :)

Comment: rows.filter((row) => row.id === yourID )) it's going to return only the objects in the array that contains the yourID value in the id property

Comment: In your constructor (because it is harcoded, otherwise it would go in your ngOnInit if you are fetching data), remember that this is going to return an array, you could store it somewhere else to use it in your template, it's up to you

Comment: Make a new question with the details of what you are trying and i will gladly help you! Including your detail component and template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141476/show-user-details-with-selected-from-ngx-data-table-at-angular